# Replacing String in the original String only

Tags: java, string, replace

During my program I am allowing a user to input a string. But then it also replaces the things in the output, so all I want it to do is replace in the original string. Thank you.

```
public class Crypto {
    public Crypto() {
        String s = f;
    }

    public String encrypt(String s) {

        String myString = s.replace("v", "ag\'r").replace("V", "ag\'r")
                .replace("m", "ssad").replace("M", "ssad")
                .replace("g", "jeb..w").replace("G", "jeb..w")
                .replace("b", "dug?/").replace("B", "dug?/");
        return myString;
    }

    public String decrypt(String d) {
        String myString = d.replace("ag‘,r", "v").replace("ssad", "m")
                .replace("jeb..w", "g").replace("dug>?/", "b");
        return myString;
    }

    public String d;
    public String s;
    public String f;
    public String myString;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is your problem? What output do you mean?

Comment: Like if I input this "This is a very big morning." it should out put "This is a ag',rery dug>?/ijeb..w ssadorninjeb..w.". But it says this "This is a ajedug?/..w'rery dug?/ijedug?/..w ssadorninjedug?/..w.".

Answer (score 2):

```
String result ="";
for(char cur:s.toCharArray()){
    switch(cur){
    case 'v':
    case 'V':
        result += "ag\'r";
        break;
    case 'm':
    case 'M':
        result += "ssad";
        break;
    case 'g':
    case 'G':
        result += "jeb..w";
        break;
    case 'b':
    case 'B':
        result += "dug?/";
        break;

    default: 
        result += cur;
        break;
    }
}
return result;
```

I used a char array and a for each loop, or using string builder:

```
StringBuilder result =new StringBuilder();
for(char cur:s.toCharArray()){
    switch(cur){
    case 'v':
    case 'V':
        result.append("ag\'r");
        break;
    case 'm':
    case 'M':
        result.append("ssad");
        break;
    case 'g':
    case 'G':
        result.append("jeb..w");
        break;
    case 'b':
    case 'B':
        result.append("dug?/");
        break;

    default: 
        result.append(cur);
        break;
    }
}
return result.toString();
```

I used a char array and a for each loop,